# Put mysql result to json file

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

i'm trying to create a json file with results from a mysql query. It works but it doubles my information for some reason and i don't know why. It adds datatable key but also array number. To understand better i'll put my code in here

```
<?php
include 'dbconfig.php';

$stmt=$dbh->prepare('Select title,start,end from Events');
$stmt->execute();
$events=$stmt->fetchAll();

file_put_contents("test.json", json_encode($events));
?>
```

**output test.json**

```
[
    {
    "title":"party",
    "0":"party",
    "start":"2016-02-24 07:00:00",
    "1":"2016-02-24 07:00:00",
    "end":"2016-02-24 10:00:00",
    "2":"2016-02-24 10:00:00"
    }
]
```

I want just title, start, end without  0,1,2
Thnx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use :  `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

```
$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Read about `FETCH_ASSOC` : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.html